# One data table coming from rest service and another one coming from SQL database, need to append the SQL dataset to existing data table

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have created a data table.

```vb
Dim restserviceDataTable As New System.Data.DataTable
restserviceDataTable = restServiceClient.MethodToFill().
```

Now I have my data table filled up with the following info :

[image]

I have queried SQL with where condition = id.

Now I have two rows with the following columns in my data set.

Now i have added the new columns to existing data table. I need to insert all my data set rows to existing data table:

```
restserviceDataTable.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
restserviceDataTable.Columns.Add("Intermediary", GetType(String))
restserviceDataTable.Columns.Add("Session", GetType(String))
```

Data set has this:

[image].

The final result I want is here:

[image: . Please let me know. TIA]

```vb
For Each datasetRows As DataRow In myDataSet. Tables(0).Rows        
    For Each dataTableRows As DataRow In restserviceDataTable.Rows
        dataTableRows = restserviceDataTable.NewRow()                                
        dataTableRows("Status") = datasetRows("Status")
        dataTableRows("Intermediary") = datasetRows("Intermediary")
        dataTableRows("Session") = datasetRows("Session")
        restserviceDataTable.ImportRow(dataTableRows)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `PrimaryKey` for each `DataTable`, you can use the `Merge` method:

```
Dim dataTable1 As New DataTable
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Abc", GetType(String))
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Xyz", GetType(String))
dataTable1.Rows.Add(44, "String1", "String1")
dataTable1.Rows.Add(190, "string2", "String2")
dataTable1.PrimaryKey = {dataTable1.Columns(0)}

Dim dataTable2 As New DataTable
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Intermediary", GetType(String))
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Session", GetType(String))
dataTable2.Rows.Add(44, "value1", "value2", "value3")
dataTable2.Rows.Add(190, "value5", "value6", "value7")
dataTable2.PrimaryKey = {dataTable2.Columns(0)}

dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
' dataTable1 now contains the merged data
```